# webpack-simple routing not working in production mode

Tags: vue-router

I am using webpack-simple template for development with vue-js 2. I am using routing throug vue-router. It works fine in the development mode

```
npm run dev
```

After building, I got build.js in the dist folder using the below command

```
npm run build
```

With index.html and dist folder, I try to run the project but fail. No error found in the console also